# String date to java sql date conversion

Tags: java, date, sqldatetime

i need to format this String date `Tue Sep 23 14:36:59 PKT 2014` to `java sql date` but i need both date and time, i tried this

```
String st = "Tue Sep 23 14:36:59 PKT 2014";
new java.sql.Date(new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy").parse(st).getTime())
```

but it returns only date part and time part is 00:00 can any one help me to sort this issue out.

Regards and thanks in advance.

Comment: Run this.  http://ideone.com/BC5w3u

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982870/string-java-util-date-java-sql-date-with-time-stamp

Comment: System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy").parse(st).toLocaleString());
System.out.println(new Date(new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy").parse(st).getTime()).getTime());
System.out.println(new Date(new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy").parse(st).getTime()).toLocaleString());

Answer (score 4, accepted):

java.sql.Date doesn't contain time information. You should look at java.sql.Timestamp instead

Answer (score 0):

As its name suggests, `java.sql.Date` is the Java equivalent of an `SQL DATE` meaning it stores years, months and days only -- no time data (as a result, note also that `java.sql.Date` isn't associated with a time zone).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
java.sql.Timestamp ourJavaTimestampObject = new java.sql.Timestamp(dateTime.getTime().getTime());
```

with dateTime is an instance of Date. It works to me.

Answer (score 0):

see this link

http://www.coderanch.com/t/304851/JDBC/databases/Java-date-MySQL-date-conversion

The following lines may solve your issue.

```
java.util.Date dt = new java.util.Date();
java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String currentTime = sdf.format(dt);
```